# Typo3 & gridelements & flexform: Flexform-Elements side by side

Tags: typo3, flexform, tx-gridelements

when I code a gridelement with a flexform for backend-layout, the elements are always top-down.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3DataStructure>
    <meta type="array">
        <langDisable>1</langDisable>
    </meta>
    <ROOT type="array">
        <type>array</type>
        <el type="array">
            <title type="array">
                <TCEforms type="array">
                    <label>Titel</label>
                    <config type="array">
                        <type>input</type>
                        <size>30</size>
                        <eval>trim,required</eval>
                    </config>
                </TCEforms>
            </title>
            <description type="array">
                <TCEforms type="array">
                    <label>Beschreibung</label>
                    <config type="array">
                        <type>input</type>
                        <size>60</size>
                        <eval>trim,required</eval>
                    </config>
                </TCEforms>
            </description>
        </el>
    </ROOT>
</T3DataStructure>
```

[image: Elements top-down]

How is it possible to show them side by side?
[image: Elements side by side]

Is this possible only with a flexform configuration?

Comment: No. FlexForm does not allow other layout options.